# Colision Resolution between Circles - Slow Sliding

Tags: python, physics, collision

I am having trouble with circle to circle collision resolution.

First, i detect the collision, then if the balls collide, i separate them by the sum of their radii and set the velocities. That's easy.

My problem is when gravity is acting and a ball collides with another ball **from above**. It's **suposed to bouce off** but instead it **slides very slowly until it drops in the ground**.

Whats hapning is that afer the colision resolution, gravity pushes the ball down and causes another colision. I've tried separating the ball by the sum of their radii + x but it just slides a little faster.

You can watch the video at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tk7qQ9KDFp0&feature=youtu.be.

And here's the code that hadles colision:

```
for p in world.particle_list:

        if not p == self:

            if self.pos.sub(p.pos).get_length() <= self.radius * ppm + p.radius * ppm:

                p_mass_ratio = float(self.mass) / (self.mass + p.mass)
                self_mass_ratio = float(p.mass) / (self.mass + p.mass)

                rel_pos = p.pos.sub(self.pos)
                shift = rel_pos.set_length(- rel_pos.get_length() + self.radius * ppm + p.radius * ppm)
                p.pos = p.pos.add(shift.scale(0.50))
                self.pos = self.pos.add(shift.scale(-0.50))

                p_speed = p.speed
                self_speed = self.speed

                self.speed = p_speed.add(self.speed.norm_reflect(rel_pos.set_angle(rel_pos.get_angle() + 90).scale(-self.friction))).scale(0.50 * self_mass_ratio)
                p.speed = self_speed.add(p.speed.norm_reflect(rel_pos.set_angle(rel_pos.get_angle() + 90).scale(self.friction))).scale(0.50 * p_mass_ratio)
```

I made a vector class to handle this:

```
def dcos(x):

    return cos(radians(x))

def dsin(x):

    return sin(radians(x))

def dtan(x):

    return tan(radians(x))

class Vec(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):

        self.x = float(x)
        self.y = float(y)

        self.length = self.get_length()
        self.angle = self.get_angle()

    def get_length(self):

        return sqrt(self.x ** 2 + self.y ** 2)

    def get_angle(self):

        return atan2(self.y, self.x) * 180 / pi

    def add(self, vec1):

        new_x = self.x + vec1.x
        new_y = self.y + vec1.y

        return Vec(new_x, new_y)

    def sub(self, vec1):

        new_x = self.x - vec1.x
        new_y = self.y - vec1.y

        return Vec(new_x, new_y)

    def scale(self, k):

        return Vec(self.x * k, self.y * k)

    def set_angle(self, a):

        new_x = self.length * dcos(a)
        new_y = self.length * dsin(a)

        if a == -90 or a == 90:

            new_x = 0

        if a == 180 or a == 0 or a == -180:

            new_y = 0

        return Vec(new_x, new_y)

    def set_length(self, l):

        new_x = l * dcos(self.angle)
        new_y = l * dsin(self.angle)

        return Vec(new_x, new_y)

    def inverse(self):

        return Vec(- self.x, - self.y)


    def norm_reflect(self, vec1):

        if self.get_angle == vec1.get_angle():

            return Vec(self.x, self.y)

        if vec1.get_angle() >= 0:

            return self.set_angle(vec1.get_angle() - self.get_angle() + 90)

    else:

        return self.set_angle(vec1.get_angle() - self.get_angle() - 90)
```

Comment: Is it legal to set length to a negative value? Does it reverse the direction of a vector?

Comment: Yes, the set_length() method will reverse the direction if argument is negative.

Answer (score 0):

(I don't know python, but I know physics and you aren't getting other answers so I'll take a crack at it.)

Look at

```
if self.pos.sub(p.pos).get_length() <= self.radius * ppm + p.radius * ppm:
  ...
  rel_pos = p.pos.sub(self.pos)
  shift = rel_pos.set_length(- rel_pos.get_length() + self.radius * ppm + p.radius * ppm)
  p.pos = p.pos.add(shift.scale(0.50))
  self.pos = self.pos.add(shift.scale(-0.50))
```

You're setting the length to a negative number, so you're moving the objects *toward* each other.

The `norm_reflect()` function doesn't make much sense, and I suspect it does something other than what you intend (in which case you're not testing your code).

These two lines:

```
self.speed = p_speed.add(self.speed.norm_reflect(rel_pos.set_angle(rel_pos.get_angle() + 90).scale(-self.friction))).scale(0.50 * self_mass_ratio)
p.speed = self_speed.add(p.speed.norm_reflect(rel_pos.set_angle(rel_pos.get_angle() + 90).scale(self.friction))).scale(0.50 * p_mass_ratio)
```

seem to be invoking `norm_reflect()` with only one argument, *and* you're bringing friction and mass ratios into the picture before the simple case is working, *and* you're reusing `rel_pos` after multiple transformations, *and* the physics is non-Newtonian (i.e. wrong enough to require starting over from a blank slate).

Comment: First, as you can see in the youtube video, i'm not moving the balls toward each other, second, if you think the norm_reflect function is wrong than please tell how is it wrong and third, every method of my vector class returns another method so there is no way I'm using transformed vectors.

Comment: Returns another vector class not a method.

Comment: 1) Try the `shift` stuff in isolation if you don't believe me, don't rely on a video in which *a lot of other stuff is going on*. 2) What do you intend `norm_reflect()` to do? Reflect one vector across another? What do you expect if the two arguments are the same? 3) Do you think that `rel_pos` is unchanged by the `self.speed =...` line?

Comment: 1) i tried the shift stuff alone and i know that there's nothing wrong with it. First i put the balls in the same position and then they separate (like in the video).2) norm_reflect() is supposed to reflect a vector of another's normal(not the problem because without gravity it doesn't have the problem).3) I printed the rel_pos before and after the calculations and they are the same.

Comment: The only parts of that that make sense indicate that you have implemented *non-standard* behavior, e.g. a `set_angle` method that doesn't actually change the angle of the calling object. Maybe you've also set `A.sub(B)` to return **B**-**A**, there's no way to tell. Maybe if you post a minimal complete example, someone can help you.

Comment: Maybe my name choosing is not the best but why do you just assume there's something wrong in the code, why don't you give me real suggestions of how to solve the problem you saw in the video?

Comment: I assumed you were following math/programming convention. Without that, and without the complete code, there's not much anyone can do. If you want advice that doesn't refer to math or the code, I suggest you try a simpler case: a ball bouncing off an angled surface, without gravity. Get that to work perfectly, then try two identical balls colliding without gravity.

Comment: The problem is when one ball collides with another that's on the ground, and because the ball that's on the ground doesn't have space to move, it goes up in the next frame, hitting the other ball but the other ball instead of going up in the air it sticks the the other and slides to the ground